# JMeter: Database load test

Tags: jmeter

I'm doing some load test on an MS SQL Database using JMeter.
I'm able to connect and read a specific record using a JDBC Request.
I would like to insert in my Table 100 records having the same fields data taken from this specific record but changing only one field (the primary key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Variable Names` or `Result Variable Name` parameters of the [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler to store your query result into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

[image]

Once done you should be able to [replace](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-using-replaceall.html) the "old" primary key value with a new one using [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and construct the request back.

We are not able to provide comprehensive instructions/code without seeing your SQL query output, in the meantime check out [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter/) article to get initial understanding on working with the JDBC-originated variables and results sets.